# Performance of UI:repeat in JSF2/Mojara

Tags: java, performance, jsf-2

In analysing the performance of a JSF2 (Mojara) page returning 200 tabular rows I'm seeing 50% of the time taken to respond being in just rendering. For the 4 seconds on a dev box, 2 are purely down to the rendering of this page.

What is the best path to improve performance?

(I've been told to replace ui:repeat with jstl code?)

Due to the complexity of the JSF object tree - the profiler isn't telling me much.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering is the most expensive task at any way. But 2 seconds is pretty a lot (those 2 seconds before rendering also by the way, sounds like poor DB performance). Aren't you heavily using conditionals inside the `UIData` component? E.g. `h:inputText disabled="#{bean.disabled}"` and so on.

It's hard to tell the best path to improve performance and it's hard to improve this in the JSF side. Aren't you unawarely including network and/or webbrowser speed in the complete picture? Poor network bandwidth and a small server side response buffer might block the one and other. Poor table rendering performance in the webbrowser might block one and other. MSIE is known to be a disaster in table rendering performance. Try FireFox or Chrome instead.

At any way, replacing `ui:repeat` with `c:forEach` isn't going to help much. Even more, the `c:forEach` is a tad less efficient since it invokes the `items` on **every** iteration instead of caching it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old query but here is a solution i have found effective in the past. It all depends on what you are rendering.

For rendering simple string lists its must faster to create a tag lib function

```
public static String collectionToString(Collection collection, String separator)
{
  if (CisNullOrEmpty(collection))
  {
    return "";
  }
    // custom join implementation
return Utils.join(collection, separator);
}
```

For more complex ones you could custom functions dependent on objects